# How do I Request data from an input field in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, request

Simple question. I have the following hidden input field on my ASP.NET page:

```
<form id="userform" method="post" action="RankingPage.aspx">
    <input type="hidden" id="email" />
    <input type="hidden" id="name" />
</form>
```

I'm trying to get the data from the field (in my code behind) like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string name = Request.Form["name"].ToString();
}
```

It's returning a null reference (which I'm assuming means it couldn't find the field). Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: This should work, unless the `name` field is not within a `<form>` tag.

Comment: Or possibly the form is a get.

Comment: I added my form to make it more clear. Page_Load is the code behind for RankingPage.aspx. This still returns a null reference...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

oh geee, i was struggeling with this myself today.

I wanted to use the hidden html field to store info inbetween partial postbacks from my update panels.

I didn't want to use the 'runat ="server" ' on my hidden field as this then screws the ID (because i'm using masterpages).

the moment i changed mine  from

```
<input type="hidden" id="manageremailHidden" />
```

to

```
<input type="hidden" id="manageremailHidden" name="manageremailHidden"/>
```

i was able to call the read the value from codebehind (on postback)

```
Public ReadOnly Property manageremailknown() As String
    Get
        Return Request.Form("manageremailHidden")
    End Get
End Property
```

cut a long story short.. you need to add the **name** property as well, otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you could use

```
<input type="hidden" runat="server" name="name" id="name" />
```

or use HiddenField control

then you can access it like Master.FindControl("name")

Answer (score 0):

How about doing this:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenSomething" runat="server" />
```

In the code behind do

```
HiddenSomething.Value
```